# Call DLLs dynamically C++

Tags: c++, dll

I have to make a DLL time tester program in c++ that can load DLL and try their functions, testing if the give a correct results and checking the time that it takes to run them. 
So this means that I will receive during the execution of my program a DLL or different ones, load them and call their functions without knowing how many params the functions have (before compiling my program).

So I understand that I can't declare pointers to functions need by `GetProcAddress` unless I declare dynamicly (I don't know if I can do this in c++).
Neither include the header of the DLL dynamically.

The only solution I can find is that my program generate a new c or c++ file with all the things necessary to call the DLL functions, compile, launch it...

Can you give me opinions, ideas, maybe there is a way to do this in C++ and I'm skipping it.

I'm using C++, with codeblock 13.12 and MinWG 4.8.

Comment: sounds like you are right, in a compiled language i don't see a cleaner alternative that code generation on the fly.

Comment: In what form would you receive a description of how to call a function? Say you need to test a function that receives two `char*`. What should you do?

Comment: The programhave access to all the information of the function, name, index, parameters, return type. But only after being compiled. And I just need to run that function getting the result (the user will check that is correct) and check the times it took to tun it. This work sounds better for a Interpreted language but they ask me to work in c++ :S

Comment: Check out Python. It has a module to load DLLs (https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) and call their functions, obviously without any previous knowledge of them. That means that the low-level interface and how to pass parameters is available there. Now, you could either use Python directly (or to build a prototype at least) or you could read the source code to find out how to do it. Nearby: Python also has a module for timing the duration of things, which would save you another few steps.

Comment: "have access to all the information". In what form? What information should be there to actually call a function that expects two `char*` arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two basic solutions to this problem.

1) fill out all the possible functions on the fly, then when you are calling a function, you can choose the correct template and fill in the details.

2) generate the code on the fly.

1) Is not as difficult as it sounds, as there are a large number of functionally identical functions.  It is possible for two functions to meet all the 0 parameter functions (stdcall + cdecl).  2 functions for one parameter call and so on.  The correct data (e.g. pointer and size) gets aliased into pointer1, pointer2 and then passed to a generic function void * Func1_2params( void*,void*);  - this may meet the calling convention of void func1( char, char);, int strtok( char *, char *);, ... as the slot (reg/stack) for each parameter element is "pointer sized"

2)  There is a library ffi (foreign form interface) - which binds script languages to C/C++ which could be used to build the code on the fly to create the correct interface, this would be not quite straight forward, but would possible to get this to work.  Finally some script languages have direct calls (java, luajit).  It would be relatively easy to embed luajit in your code, and use a small amount of lua to build a callsite from "lua view" of a function to native, and then call a DLL.

Comment: Thank you!, this really reduce the options, maybe i can set a max of params accepted. And if I want to get the result of the function?, Just with a cast from void* to the correct type will work? Example: typedef void* (* Myfunc) (void * ,void *); ....... Myfunc myfunc(0);.... int n=(int)(myfunc)(db,something);